# Sorting HTML table (with anchor tags and data in cells) in Python

Tags: python, html, sorting, html-table

I have a necessity to sort a given HTML table of the following structure, in Python.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">ABCD</a></td>
        <td>A23BND</td>
        <td><a title="ABCD">345345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">EFG</a></td>
        <td>Add4D</td>
        <td><a title="EFG">3432</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">HG</a></td>
        <td>GJJ778</td>
        <td><a title="HG">2341333</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I am doing something like this:

```
container = tree.findall("tr")
strOut = ""
data = []
for elem in container:
    key = elem.findtext(colName)
    data.append((key, elem))

data.sort()
```

The problem is that it sorts by the text inside the `<td>`. I want to be able to sort by the anchor value and not href.

What can I do to achieve that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sorts by the text because that's what you're extracting as the key when you do

```
key = elem.findtext(colName)
```

I imagine `colName` is some tag string, and `findtext` will just find the text of the first subelement matching that tag.  If what you want instead is to use as the key the value of some attribute (e.g. `title`?) of an `<a>`,

```
for ana in elem.findall('a'):
    key = ana.get('title')
    if key is not None: break
```

Would do that.  Exactly **what** do you want to use as the key?

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` method has the valueable `key` and `cmp` arguments which you can use for custom sorting. If you augment the `data` data structure with the extra information you need for sorting, you can use either `key` or `cmp` (depending on exact need) in the call to `sort` to achieve what you want. Here's a simple example:

```
In [60]: ids = [1, 2, 3]
In [61]: score = {1: 20, 2: 70, 3: 40}
In [62]: ids.sort(key=lambda x: score[x])
In [63]: ids
Out[63]: [1, 3, 2]
```

Here, I sorted the `ids` list according to the score of each `id` taken from the `score` dictionary.

Comment: @Eli, that's fine, but so's the OP code which uses the older "decorate, sort, undecorate" idiom from before Python's sort gained the `key=` argument.  The problem has nothing to do with that: it's all about the proper way of extracting the key in the OP's specific case.

Comment: @Alex: you're right. To me it also wasn't clear what is the key the OP is interested in, so I settled for telling him of a more idiomatic way to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this wasn't your question, but best practice for this sort of thing is to use Javascript. You will get a much better user experience on your website (if that's what you're doing).

This js library is excellent and easy to use:
   http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

Comment: The reason I want Python to do it because the table is too big for browser to handle it. Hence, the sorting at server side is necessary. I do have a JS implementation I am using currently.